# Como agregar este patrón regex delante para imponer una restricción de búsqueda mas, pero sin afectar la captura del grupo de captura?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, replace

```py
import re, datetime

def replace_month_number_with_month_name(input_text):

    if input_text == "11": input_text = input_text.replace("11", "noviembre", 1)

    elif input_text == "01": input_text = input_text.replace("01", "enero", 1)
    elif input_text == "1":  input_text = input_text.replace("1", "enero", 1)

    return input_text


#Examples:
input_text = 'de el dia 10 a las 00:00 am hasta el 15 a las 20:00 pm del 11 del año 2020' #example 1
input_text = 'del 11 del año 2020' #example 2, si uso la condicion con replacement_conditioner delante no deberia modificarlo

replacement_conditioner = r"(?:del|de\s*el|de)\s*(?:d[íi]a|)\s*\d{2}\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la)\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm)|)\s*(?:hasta|al|a )\s*(?:el|)\s*(?:d[íi]a|)\s*\d{2}\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la)\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm)|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de)\s*(?:mes|)\s*"
search_pattern = replacement_conditioner + r"\b(?:0[1-9]|1[1-2])\b(?=\s(?:(?:\w+\s){4})?(?:del\s*a[ñn]o|de\s*el)\s*\d*|\s*\b(\d{4})\b)"

#Este patron de busqueda si funciona pero me gustaria agregarle una condicion mas, y es que antes de encontrar este patron antes debe estar lo que el patron replacement_conditioner  esta indicando
#search_pattern = r"\b(?:0[1-9]|1[1-2])\b(?=\s(?:(?:\w+\s){4})?(?:del\s*a[ñn]o|de\s*el)\s*\d*|\s*\b(\d{4})\b)"

input_text = re.sub(search_pattern,
                    #lambda m: print(repr(m[0])),
                    lambda m : replace_month_number_with_month_name(m[0]),
                    input_text, re.IGNORECASE)


print(repr(input_text))
```

Este es el output que debería conseguir con este nuevo patrón de búsqueda, ya que el objetivo es establecer una condición delantera adicional, la cual esta hecha con el patrón contenido en la variable `replacement_conditioner`

Si esto funcionase igual que la regex  `r"\b(?:0[1-9]|1[1-2])\b(?=\s(?:(?:\w+\s){4})?(?:del\s*a[ñn]o|de\s*el)\s*\d*|\s*\b(\d{4})\b)"` debería obtener tambien este output :

```
'de el dia 10 a las 00:00 am hasta el 15 a las 20:00 pm del november del año 2020' #for example 1

'del 11 del año 2020' #for example 2, solo se modificara "11" por "noviembre" si no se coloco delante la condicion replacement_conditioner
```

Es algo un poco extraño (o almenos no me estoy dando cuenta) que colocar el patrón ese delante, impida la extracción del grupo de captura que es el mes. Luego de extraer el grupo de captura si funcionase bien enviaría el `"11"` a la función `replace_month_number_with_month_name()` en la cual se realizaria el reemplazo `"11"` ---> `"noviembre"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Para lograrlo podrías utilizar un [`look-behind`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-regex-lookbehind/) de tu primer `regex` para que únicamente cuando esté presente se valide el `11`, pero hay un pequeño problema, `look-behind` necesita tener un ancho fijo y tu `regex` tiene ancho variable ya que utilizas muchos `*`

Una solución es utilizar [`\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) que en pocas palabras es un `look-behind` con ancho variable (Revisa el url para entender bien como funciona), pero hay otro pequeño problema, la librería `re` no soporta `\K`

Hay otra librería, su nombre es [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) que si lo soporta y que según lei, se utiliza bastante cuando hay que trabajar con `regex` complejos.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import regex, datetime

def replace_month_number_with_month_name(input_text):
    if input_text == "11": input_text = input_text.replace("11", "noviembre", 1)

    elif input_text == "01": input_text = input_text.replace("01", "enero", 1)
    elif input_text == "1":  input_text = input_text.replace("1", "enero", 1)

    return input_text


input_text1 = 'de el dia 10 a las 00:00 am hasta el 15 a las 20:00 pm del 11 del año 2020' #example 1
input_text2 = 'del 11 del año 2020'

replacement_conditioner = r"(?:del|de\s*el|de)\s*(?:d[íi]a|)\s*\d{2}\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la)\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm)|)\s*(?:hasta|al|a )\s*(?:el|)\s*(?:d[íi]a|)\s*\d{2}\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la)\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm)|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de)\s*(?:mes|)\s*"
search_conditioner = r"\b(?:0[1-9]|1[1-2])\b(?=\s(?:(?:\w+\s){4})?(?:del\s*a[ñn]o|de\s*el)\s*\d*|\s*\b(\d{4})\b)"
search_pattern = fr'({replacement_conditioner}\K){search_conditioner}'
#search_pattern = r'(((?:del|de\s*el|de)\s*(?:d[íi]a|)\s*\d{2}\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la)\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm)|)\s*(?:hasta|al|a )\s*(?:el|)\s*(?:d[íi]a|)\s*\d{2}\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la)\s*(?:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm)|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de)\s*(?:mes|)\s*)\\K)\b(?:0[1-9]|1[1-2])\b(?=\s(?:(?:\w+\s){4})?(?:del\s*a[ñn]o|de\s*el)\s*\d*|\s*\b(\d{4})\b)'

input_text1 = regex.sub(search_pattern,
                    #lambda m: print(repr(m[0])),
                    lambda m : replace_month_number_with_month_name(m[0]),
                    input_text1, regex.IGNORECASE)

input_text2 = regex.sub(search_pattern,
                    #lambda m: print(repr(m[0])),
                    lambda m : replace_month_number_with_month_name(m[0]),
                    input_text2, regex.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text1))
print(repr(input_text2))
```

Esto imprime:

```
'de el dia 10 a las 00:00 am hasta el 15 a las 20:00 pm del noviembre del año 2020'
'del 11 del año 2020'
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto. La verdad nunca habia usado esta librería `regex` extendida de python, entonces si entendí bien usas ese carácter de escape `\K` que viene incluido en esta librería de `regex` extendida, para imponerle al patrón de búsqueda que aquellos patrones que se encuentren definidos entre los paréntesis previos a ese `\K` tengan que estar si o si presentes pero sin que estos sean capturados?

Comment: Exacto, `look-behind` indica que un caracter, o en este caso un grupo, deban estar presentes para la validación de lo que esté después, pero como `look-behind` necesita ancho fijo (Es decir, un número específico de caracteres), entonces no podemos utilizar el típico `?<=`, pero `\K` cumple una función similar pero permite ancho variable.

Comment: Por cierto `\K` no es específico de esa librería, es estándar, solo que no está disponible en `re`

Comment: Realmente muchísimas gracias por la explicación, veo que es bastante útil usar para estos casos `( )\K` respecto del lookbehind  `(?<= )` que viene en el regex engine que usa la típica librería `re` de python

Comment: Estuve intentando otras opciones con grupos con la librería `re` pero estaba tomando mucho tiempo así que mejor propuse esa otra opción.