# Por que estos negative-lookahead no estan logrando restringir un patron regex que decide cuando realizar sustituciones con la funcion re.sub()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, str-replace

```py
import re

#Example input:
input_text = "en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las 2023_-_02_-_04 19:00 pm aasassa  2023_-_02_-_04 sdshdhshj 19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 fgfg"

date_format_00 = r"(\d*)_-_(\d{2})_-_(\d{2})"  # Y*_-_MM_DD
identificate_hours = r"(?:(\d{1,2})|)(?:(?:\:| )(\d{1,2})|)\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)"

#I use a negative lookahead "(?!\()" to avoid matches
date_format_00_blocking = r"(?!\d*_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}\s*)"
identificate_hours_blocking = r"(?!\d{1,2}(?:\:| )\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm|))"


#Ambos deberia lograr reemplazos del tipo:  "2023_-_02_-_04"  --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(00:00 am))"
#sin embargo solo el primero de los re.sub() (en el orden de la lectura del codigo que hace el interprete) lo hará, ya que tras ello ya estara etiquetado con los parentesis

#Only replacements of the type:  "2023_-_02_-_04 19:00" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"
input_text = re.sub(r"(?!\()" + identificate_hours_blocking + r"\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*(?:a\s*la(?:s| )|)\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*" + date_format_00_blocking + r"\s*(?!\))",
                    lambda m: (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_{m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> print after first  re.sub()

#Only replacements of the type:  "19:00 2023_-_02_-_04" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"
input_text = re.sub(r"(?!\()" + date_format_00_blocking + r"\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de |)\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*" + identificate_hours_blocking + r"\s*(?!\))",
                    lambda m: (f"({m[5]}_-_{m[6]}_-_{m[7]}({m[1] or '00'}:{m[2] or '00'} {m[3] or m[4] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> print after second re.sub()
```

Dado el input recibido en la variable `input_text`, se deben realizar 2 reemplazos usando la función `re.sub()` (o algo similar), pero estos reemplazos se deben realizar solo bajo ciertas condiciones. He intentado muchas veces restringir estas posibilidades para que los reemplazos no deseados no se realicen prematuramente dentro del código.

Ninguna de estas dos funciones `re.sub()` debería modificar la fecha y hora `Y*_MM_DD hh:ss am or pm`  que están protegidas por paréntesis, como esta `(Y*_MM_DD(hh:ss am or pm) )`. Por esta razón he puesto estas restricciones al principio `(?!\()` y al final `(?!\))`

El primer `re.sub()` no debería reemplazar las fechas si se especifica `hora:minutos` antes.

El segundo `re.sub()` no debería reemplazar las fechas si se especifica `hora:minutos` detrás.

Por alguna razón desconocida, **mi negative-lookahead no funciona** y obtengo este **output incorrecto**:

```
#wrong output print after first  re.sub()
'en la montaña a las ((2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))(19:00 pm)) o a las(2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm))aasassa(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))sdshdhshj 19:00 pm(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))fgfg'

#wrong output print after second re.sub()
'en la montaña a las ((2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))(19:00 pm)) o a las(2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm))aasassa(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))sdshdhshj 19:00 pm(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))fgfg'
```

Y este es el **output correcto** que estoy tratando de obtener:

```
#correct output print after first  re.sub()
'en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) aasassa  (2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am)) sdshdhshj 19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 fgfg'

#correct output print after second re.sub()
'en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) aasassa  (2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am)) sdshdhshj (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) fgfg'
```

---

EDIT usando librería `regex`

```py
import regex

#Example input:
input_text = "en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las 2023_-_02_-_04 19:00 pm aasassa  2023_-_02_-_04 sdshdhshj 19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 fgfg"

date_format_00 = r"(\d*)_-_(\d{2})_-_(\d{2})" # Y*_-_MM_DD

#identificate_hours = r"(?:(\d{1,2})|)(?:\:|)(?:(\d{1,2})|)\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)"
#identificate_hours = r"(?:(\d{1,2})|)(?:\:| )(?:(\d{1,2})|)\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)"
identificate_hours = r"(?:(\d{1,2})|)(?:(?:\:| )(\d{1,2})|)\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)" 

date_format_00_blocking = r"(?!\d*_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}\s*)"

identificate_hours_blocking = r"(?!\d{1,2}(?:\:| )\d{1,2}\s*(?:a|p)m)"
#identificate_hours_blocking = r"(?!\d{2}(?:\:| )\d{2}\s(?:a|p)m)"

#Solo reemplazos del tipo:  "2023_-_02_-_04 19:00" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"
input_text = regex.sub(
                    r"(?!\()" + r"(" + identificate_hours_blocking + r")\K" + r"\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*(?:a\s*la(?:s| )|)\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*" + date_format_00_blocking + r"\s*(?!\))",
                    lambda m: (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_{m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, flags = regex.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text))


#Solo reemplazos del tipo:  "19:00 2023_-_02_-_04" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"
input_text = regex.sub(
                    r"(?!\()" + date_format_00_blocking + r"\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de |)\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*" + identificate_hours_blocking + r"\s*(?!\))",
                    lambda m: (f"({m[5]}_-_{m[6]}_-_{m[7]}({m[1] or '00'}:{m[2] or '00'} {m[3] or m[4] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, flags = regex.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text))
```

Da un mal output:

```
'en la montaña a las ((_-_2023_-_02(04:00 am))(19:00 pm)) o a las(_-_2023_-_02(04:19 00))aasassa(_-_2023_-_02(04:00 am))sdshdhshj 19:00 pm(_-_2023_-_02(04:00 am))fgfg'

'en la montaña a las ((_-_2023_-_02(04:00 am))(19:00 pm)) o a las(_-_2023_-_02(04:19 00))aasassa(_-_2023_-_02(04:00 am))sdshdhshj 19:00 pm(_-_2023_-_02(04:00 am))fgfg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifiquemos un poco tu pregunta, que se puede llevar a un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

¿Por qué el lookahead en este regex

```
(?!x)a
```

no impide que coincida con este texto?:

```
hhh xa xxx
```

La respuesta se hace evidente cuando se entiende que el motor de regex intenta una coincidencia desde cada posición del texto, avanzando un caracter cada vez que no logra una coincidencia.

De esa forma, cuando se intenta una coincidencia desde la posición marcada con `|`

```
hhh x|a xxx
```

no está "*seguida por `x`*", y desde ahí perfectamente puede coincidir con `a`. Evidentemente no está seguido por `x`. De hecho, si va a coincidir con una `a`, claramente no está seguido por una `x`. Sin embargo, esto se ve fácil al simplificar el ejemplo, pero si mirás en lo que estabas intentando, podés ver que en el patrón hay algo como `(?!\()\d`.

Entonces, ¿cuál es la estrategia para evitar esa coincidencia?

Para casos muy sencillos, se puede utilizar un look behind, teniendo en cuenta que están limitados, que tienen que ser de largo fijo y que no son de lo más eficientes. Por ejemplo, para una `a` que no esté precedida por `x`

```
(?<!x)a
```

Para casos más complejos conviene incluir los caracteres previos en el patrón, ya sea intentando que coincida desde la posición inicial del texto `^`, desde un separador como puede ser un espacio, o desde un límite de palabra `\b` por ejemplo.

Si modificamos el regex por algo como

```
(?:^| )[^ x]*a
```

entonces vamos a poder obtener todo el texto desde el último espacio hasta una `a`, siempre que no pase por una `x` en el medio.

Llevémoslo a algo más concreto y cercano al caso que estás queriendo reemplazar. Si el problema lo estás teniendo con el texto entre paréntesis, lo mejor es asegurarte que coincida **desde el inicio del texto** con todo lo que no es un paréntesis

```
^[^)]*?(?:Coincidencia fuera de paréntesis|\((?!Lo que no puede pasar adentro de un paréntesis)Texto a coincidir)
```

De la misma forma, también se puede hacer coincidir a todos los paréntesis que no se quiera reemplazar, con un patrón como

```
^[^(]*?(?:\(Paréntesis a excluir\)[^(]*?)*?Lo que está afuera de paréntesis y tiene que coincidir
```

---

> El código busca hacer este reemplazo `"19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04"` --> `"(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"` pero solo si detrás de la fecha no hay otra hora, por ejemplo si hay `"19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 11:20 am"`

En ese caso, hagamos que coincida con una hora+fecha que **no esté seguida por** otra hora:

```
\b\d{2}:\d{2} [ap]m \d{4}(?:_-_\d{2}){2}(?!\W+\d{2}:\d{2} [ap]m)
```

En este caso usamos un lookahead negativo **después** del patrón para hora+fecha.

Comment: mmm... y si fijo la cantidad de números, si o si a dos `\d{2}` y ademas en lugar de tomar opcional la aparición de am o pm los considero obligatorios, y de este modo tendria una cantidad fija de caracteres a capturar quedándome algo asi `r"(?!\d{2}(?:\:| )\d{2}\s*(?:a|p)m)"` , pero el problema es que en ese caso  es que sigue fallando y si coloco un look behind `r"(?<!` me da un error `re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: Según https://regex101.com/ un lookahead de ve así `a(?!x)`. Un lookbehind así `(?<!x)a`. Por favor aclara las ideas.

Comment: @Mateo Pero lo escribí bien, igual lo aclaro por que capaz confunde la manera con que me exprese en el comentario. Si uso **lookahead**  `r"(?!\d{2}(?:\:| )\d{2}\s*(?:a|p)m)"` la restricción no sirve y obtengo el mismo output que al final de mi pregunta, pero si uso un **lookbehind** , es decir, `r"(?<!\d{2}(?:\:| )\d{2}\s*(?:a|p)m)` obtengo un error `re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` . ¿Qué debería hacer?

Comment: @Pollo al inicio, en el primer bloque de código. Se me hace que escribirlo así `(?!x)a` es lo mismo que escribirlo así `xa` y es más simple.

Comment: @Pollo Si estuve leyendo eso en la documentación de los lookhead y lookbehind para el motor regex que usa python, pero aun asi usando las 2 formas de patrón que indique en el comentario que le respondí a Mateo, ninguna de ellas funciona (incluso cuando mantengo un rango de caracteres fijo). Sé que hay algo que seguramente no estoy teniendo en cuenta aparte de lo de la longitud de los caracteres que corregí, pero no tengo idea de que puede ser. :S

Comment: Se está volviendo una conversación larga, pero no creen que sería más fácil hacerlo sin lookahead ni lookbehind? Al menos los positivos. Los negativos me parecen difíciles de reemplazar. @Matias podes probar explicando qué querés lograr así pensamos en otras regex.

Comment: @Mateo está bien así como está y está reflejando lo que el autor de la pregunta estaba intentando. Pero si tenés alguna consulta sobre eso, podés realizar una pregunta en el sitio

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez mi respuesta apunta a lo siguiente: no uses una aserción para excluir lo que está antes del texto... En cambio, usá un patrón que **coincida** únicamente con lo que sí puede estar antes asegurándote así que sea correcto, más lo que realmente querías que coincida

Comment: @Pollo Si estuve viendo eso, de hecho note que en el patrón hay que evitar `\s*`, `\s+`, `(?am|pm|)` , `(?:(?:a|p)m|)`, o cualquier regex que permita una variabilidad del nro de caracteres de la cadena a restringir, quedándome la expresión como `r"(?!\d{2}(?:\:| )\d{2}\s(?:a|p)m)"` la cual tampoco logra restringir (es como si no estuviese). Despues respecto a cambiar `r"(?` por `r"(<?` solo genera la aparición del error `re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`. Pero lo que es super curioso es que en la docu no veo otra condición ademas de lo del nro de caracteres(que debe ser fijo)

Comment: @Pollo El código busca hacer este reemplazo  `"19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"`  pero solo si detrás de la fecha no hay otra hora, por ejemplo si hay `"19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 11:20 am"`. Esa necesidad de establecer una especie de restricción ante la aparición de la substring de una indicación de hora delante me llevo a que deba recurrir a las lookbehinds, de ahi que el código se acomplejase tanto. Capaz se te ocurre alguna alternativa pero yo no conosco otra

Comment: El patrón que representa a una indicación de **hora:minuto** , es el patrón que esta almacenado en la variable `identificate_hours_blocking` , por eso es donde intente colocar el `(?!` quedando finalmente ese intento de patrón restrictivo `r"(?!\d{2}(?:\:| )\d{2}\s(?:a|p)m)"` , a simple vista parece tener lógica porque quedo un patrón de captura que siempre bloquearía una cantidad fija de caracteres

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez, para hacer un `look-behind` de ancho variable puedes revisar [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/577140/171630) otra respuesta, que casualmente es a otra de tus preguntas...

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Ya intente usando la librería `regex` (la extendida), pero no arroja resultados demasiado diferentes, de hecho he editado la pregunta y al final coloque una versión del código con el mismo error pero usando la librería  `regex` en lugar de `re` y `()\K`

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez agregué un último ejemplo... Si te sirve genial, si no, espero que te ayude a entender el concepto que trataba de transmitir, y ojalá otro pueda responder lo que estás buscando

Comment: @Pollo Me sirvio muchicimo, de hecho en base a eso le di unas modificaciones y consegui obtener un resultado bastante similar al output correcto usando `identificate_hours_blocking = r"\b(\d{2}):(\d{2}) ([ap]m) (\d{4})_-_(\d{2})_-_(\d{2})(?!\W+\d{2}:\d{2} [ap]m)"` y luego hago el reemplazo con `input_text = re.sub(identificate_hours_blocking, lambda m: (f"({m[4]}_-_{m[5]}_-_{m[6]}({m[1] or '00'}:{m[2] or '00'} {m[3] or 'am'}))"), input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE )`